# Reactor Netty custom access log, missing connected user details

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

In a Spring Cloud Gateway application, I'm trying to understand how I can add the connected user in my access log. The `user` property in `AccessLogArgProvider` is always at the default value (`-`).

I'm guessing it's because I'm not providing Netty with the required details, but I couln't find how it's done.

User details are present in a Reactive context, however I don't see how I can combine reading a reactive context with the code that customize my access log.

My custom access log definition:

```java
@Component
public class NettyWebServerCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {

    // [ACCESS] IP user [time] "method uri protocol" status referer user-agent elapseTime
    public static final String LOG_FORMAT = "[ACCESS] {} {} [{}] \"{} {} {}\" {} {} {} {} {}";

    private static final String MISSING = "-";

    @Override
    public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory) {

        factory.addServerCustomizers(httpServer -> httpServer.accessLog(true,
                x -> AccessLog.create(LOG_FORMAT,
                        formatRemoteAddress(x.connectionInformation()),
                        x.user(),
                        formatDate(x.accessDateTime()),
                        x.method(),
                        x.uri(),
                        x.protocol(),
                        x.status(),
                        x.contentLength() > -1 ? x.contentLength() : MISSING,
                        x.requestHeader(HttpHeaders.REFERER) != null ? x.requestHeader(HttpHeaders.REFERER) : MISSING,
                        x.requestHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT) != null ? x.requestHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT) : MISSING,
                        x.duration())));
    }
}
```

Any pointer would be appreciated.